# Angular $q causes stack overflow

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Getting some strange behavior with $q.It calls itself infinite and freezes my PC.Don 't know what is wrong... Maybe because I am resolving on img onload event? Here is the code from factory and controller

```
function setImgSize(picFile) {

  var deferred = $q.defer();

  var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
  var imgDOMElement = angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName('test-dialog')[0])
  var compElement = window.getComputedStyle(imgDOMElement[0], null);

  var width = compElement.getPropertyValue("width");
  var height = compElement.getPropertyValue("height");
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(picFile);

  img.onload = function() {


    if (img.width >= (+width.slice(0, -2) - 50)) {
      deferred.resolve("true message placeholder");
    } else {
      deferred.reject("false message placeholder");

    }

    console.log(img.width)
  }

  return deferred.promise;

}

return {
  setImgSize: setImgSize
}
```

controller is nested DialogController inside another controller.I am building Angular material app...

```
$scope.setImagePlaceholder = function(picFile) {

    var file = picFile.type;
    DocumentFactory.setImgSize(picFile).then(function(res) {

        console.log("response is : " + res);
        $scope.resizeImg = true;

    }, function(err) {


        console.log(err);
    });

    if (/image/gi.test(file)) {
        return picFile;

    }

    return 'https://scontent-fra3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/13427833_10156897153540018_1661210034952098241_n.jpg?oh=6124bc10ca57d3b46c845494dd7c0833&oe=57E71A2B';

}
```

Comment: Please try formatting code so it has consistent indents and is readable

Comment: How do you know it is $q's fault in the code given?

Comment: It didn't freeze my PC before I did not add that code

Comment: Where does it "call itself infinite"? The code you posted does not. Also add the part that calls this function in the first place. The stack trace of the exception would help as well.

Comment: @Bergi you are right, I should have put that function in onchange event but it is on some functions that sets src attr. Now it is fine...

Comment: @Alexa: If you've solved it, you should either delete the question or [answer it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)